# Angular2 - router outlet and structure

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm very new to Angular2 and I guess this question is very basic and simple but I wasn't sure what is the right answer even though I googled it a lot!

1. Do the router-outlet and routerlink must be in the same template?
   Lets say I have menu with all the link - does my routeroutlet must be on the same menu template?
2. I read [Angular style guide](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#app-structure-and-angular-modules) and building my app according to their example but I do not understand what is the right way to add SASS files? how to use variables file for example? where is the right place to include other assets like images and fonts?

Comment: The right way is not that you think of but the one that you don't...

Comment: Please create another question (Ask Question) for number 2.